# Retrieving data from Excel spreadsheet to Excel spreadsheet in a block

Tags: excel, oledb, adodb, vba

Here's my problem :
I want to retrieve data from an Excel XML spreadsheet (*.xlsx) within another Excel spreadsheet without opening it. So I gave a chance to OLEDB with the ACE Provider.

The connection worked and I made what I wanted, by looping through my recordset. But now I want some optimization, i.e. putting my recordset into excel in a block instead of looping through it.

Therefore I made something like this :

```
Sub RetrieveData()

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With con
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"   
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=Path\File.xlsx; _
        Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"""
    .Open
    Set rs = .Execute("Select * From [Sheet1$]")

'Problem here
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(rs.RecordCount, rs.Fields.Count - 1)) = rs
   .Close
End With
Exit Sub
```

The thing here, is that I'm currently dealing with technologies which I don't know much about them and can't find any documentation on them (e.g. Microsoft ACE 12.0 Provider for OLEDB).

Regards.

(And don't even hesitate to correct my poor grammar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
Cells(1,1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Quite simple, don't you think. But put it instead of this line:

```
Range(Cells(1,1)................ = rs
```

And remember to remove comment: `'Problem here` :)

By the way, data you get in your sheet don't include columns heading. But I hope you'll cope with that separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This works great !
Just wondering : how did you figured this out ?
It would be better for everyone if I could just solve my problems myself ;)

Comment: Some years of experiences :) for some additional information you could check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839240%28v=office.14%29.aspx)...